# MSSQL Get max value from multiple columns by an ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group, top-n

I've come across many similar posts on this but none I've found got this specific.

Here's my sample data:

```
ID      CID     NARID   NATID       NADate      EID     AEDate
1       1655    1       4           12/1/12     202     6/4/14 11:37:01
2       1655    1       7           12/1/12     202     6/4/14 11:37:12
5       1655    2       65          1/13/14     587     6/4/14 11:37:00
29      3165    1       6           4/15/14     7       6/4/14 11:37:00
300     3165    1       6           6/30/14     7       6/4/14 11:33:50
295     3165    2       64          6/11/14     7       6/4/14 11:37:00
302     3165    2       63          7/24/14     7       6/4/14 11:41:24
303     3165    2       67          7/24/14     7       6/4/14 15:59:06
```

I first am looking to get the max NADate for each CID & NARID:

```
ID      CID     NARID   NATID       NADate      EID     AEDate
1       1655    1       4           12/1/12     202     6/4/14 11:37:01
2       1655    1       7           12/1/12     202     6/4/14 11:37:12
5       1655    2       65          1/13/14     587     6/4/14 11:37:00
300     3165    1       6           6/30/14     7       6/4/14 11:33:50
302     3165    2       63          7/24/14     7       6/4/14 11:41:24
303     3165    2       67          7/24/14     7       6/4/14 15:59:06
```

Then from these results, get the record with the max AEDate (along with all other corresponding fields):

```
ID      CID     NARID   NATID       NADate      EID     AEDate
2       1655    1       7           12/1/12     202     6/4/14 11:37:12
5       1655    2       65          1/13/14     587     6/4/14 11:37:00
300     3165    1       6           6/30/14     7       6/4/14 11:33:50
303     3165    2       67          7/24/14     7       6/4/14 15:59:06
```

The database type is MSSQL 2005.

Comment: +1 for actually have a not-very-common variant on a relatively common problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to use `dense_rank()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             dense_rank() over (partition by cid
                                order by nadate desc, cast(edate as date) desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

You need the `cast(edate to date)` so the query will be considering only the date portion of `edate`.  You need the `dense_rank()` so the will return all rows on the most recent date.

Comment: You're grouping on `cid`, but the question asks for a group by on `cid, narid`.  Also, if you cast `as date`, you will discard the time part for ordering

Comment: With a couple modifications based on your solution, this did the trick:

    SELECT t.*
    FROM (
     SELECT t.*,
      dense_rank() OVER (
       PARTITION BY cid,
       narid ORDER BY nadate DESC,
        aedate DESC
       ) AS seqnum
     FROM TABLE t
     ) t
    WHERE seqnum = 1;

Answer (score 2):

You can use `row_number()` to assign numbers within each `(cid, narid)` group.  If you assign the row numbers ordered by `nadate desc, aedate desc`, the rows with row number `1` will be the rows you're looking for:

```
select  *
from    (
        select  row_number() over (
                    partiton by cid, narid
                    order by nadate desc, aedate desc) as rn
        ,       *
        from    YourTable
        ) as SubQueryAlias
where   rn = 1
```

Comment: If there's a possibility of having two identical records within your data (with the exception of the ID), it appears this solution will exclude the duplicated row where the above solution using dense_rank() does not. While this scenario would never occur in my data, it is also a workable solution that may apply to others where duplicated rows occur. Adding *, prior to the row_number() was necessary to show all columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
    WITH TEMP AS
        (    
        SELECT CID,NARID,MAX(NADATE)  AS TEMPDATE
        FROM TABLE
        GROUP BY CID,NARID
        )
    SELECT A.ID,A.CID,A.NARID,A.NATID,A.NADate,A.EID,MAX(A.AEDate)
      FROM TABLE A INNER JOIN TEMP 
    ON A.CID=TEMP.CID AND A.NARID=TEMP.NARID AND A.NADATE=TEMP.TEMPDATE
    GROUP BY A.ID,A.CID,A.NARID,A.NATID,A.NADate,A.EID;
```

Comment: This will grab the top `nadate`, but it will not resolve ties using `aedate`